# Repeated key down event hangs/stops firing after some time

Tags: pygame

Consider the following program:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

class Player(object):

    def __init__(self, world):
        self.x = 100
        self.y = 100
        self.size = 30
        self.world = world

    def draw(self, windowSurface):
        pos = (self.x, self.y, self.size, self.size)
        pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, WHITE, pos)

    def moveUp(self):
        self.y -= 1
    def moveDown(self):
        self.y += 1
    def moveLeft(self):
        self.x -= 1
    def moveRight(self):
        self.x += 1

class OpenIsaac(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400), 0, 32)
        pygame.display.set_caption('OpenIsaac')
        pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 2)
        self.player = Player(self)
        self.objects = [self.player]

    def mainLoopStep(self):
        self.windowSurface.fill(BLACK)
        for object_ in self.objects:
            object_.draw(self.windowSurface)
        pygame.display.update()

    def doQuit(self):
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

    def handleQuit(self, event):
        if event.type != QUIT:
            return
        self.doQuit()

    def handleKeyboard(self, event):
        if event.type != KEYDOWN:
            return
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_ESCAPE]:
            self.doQuit()
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_LEFT]:
            self.player.moveLeft()
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_RIGHT]:
            self.player.moveRight()
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_DOWN]:
            self.player.moveDown()
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]:
            self.player.moveUp()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                self.handleQuit(event)
                self.handleKeyboard(event)
            self.mainLoopStep()
            pygame.event.pump()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    OpenIsaac().run()
```

When I move the character pressing one or two keys for some time, the character stops movement at some point. I need to release the key and press it again to restore movement. What could cause that?

Answer (score 0):

It is because when Pygame receives one key press, it will move the sprite once according to the code and only once. You will need to find a way to make the program recognize that the key is being held down, and let the program keep the sprite moving. One way is to use `pygame.key.set_repeat`. It looks similar to this:

```
delay = 100
interval = 50
pygame.key.set_repeat(delay, interval)
```

`delay` is number of milliseconds the game "waits" before repeating the keys. `interval` is the amount of milliseconds between each key event. For example, I put `delay` at 100. The game will wait for 100 milliseconds before repeating the key events. Setting `interval` at 50 will have each key event be 50 milliseconds apart.

## Python 2.x

Place these three lines right before the `while` loop. The lines should not belong in a function or functions. Holding the key down will repeat the appropriate event, such as continuing moving, jumping, etc.

## Python 3.x

I'm new to it, so you might have to find that out through Youtube or Pygame Docs. Sorry!

Setting `delay` to 1 will terminate the `key.set_repeat`. Making it higher to like 100 will have no effect and the user won't notice it. Same goes to your `interval` value. I hope it helps you now!